# How to passe value from dropdown made by semantic ui in react

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I have problem with this select by semantic ui. I made object with values I mapping it, state is changing but value in Select is not updating - if I put props as default value, it is like hard coded, and not changing at all. So what i can do (e target value doesnt work) to pass the selected icon to change props state? Should i use hook?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';



const Dropdown = () => {
    let icons = [
        {
            "v1": "home",
            "ico": "home"
        },
        {
            "v1": "cart",
            "ico": "cart"
        },
        {
            "v1": "folder",
            "ico": "folder"
        },
        {
          "v1": "group",
          "ico": "group"
      },
      {
          "v1": "dollar",
          "ico": "dollar"
      },
      {
          "v1": "users",
          "ico": "users"
      },
      {
        "v1": "briefcase",
        "ico": "briefcase"
    },
    {
        "v1": "globe",
        "ico": "globe"
    },
    {
        "v1": "calendar",
        "ico": "calendar"
    },
    {
      "v1": "favorite",
      "ico": "favorite"
    },
    ];
    
    const options = icons.map(({ v1, ico }) => ({ value: v1, icon: ico }))


    return(
        <div>
        <Dropdown
        text='Add icon'
        icon='add circle'
        floating
        labeled
        button
        className='icon'
        value={prop.icon}
        options={options}
        name='icon'
      ></Dropdown>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an onChange function to the component that receives two arguments: `event` and `result`. The `result` argument is an object that has a key `value` with the selected value of the dropdown. You then need to use the `useState` hook to save the selected value in the component state.

Hence, you could do something like this:

```
 import {useState} from "react"

 const [value, setValue] = useState("")

 const handleChange = (e, result) => {
      // result.value is the selected value from the Dropdown
      setValue(result.value)
  }

 <Dropdown
  onChange={handleChange}
  />
```